# I'm trying to install xamp 5.2.6 (xp service pack 1) and conect with SQLSRV

Tags: php, drupal-7, windows-xp, sqlsrv

I have download xampp 1.6.8 with php 5.2.6.
I have download SQLSRV 2.0. and out put into c:\xampp\php\ext\

I have try in my php.ini: `extension = php_pdo_sqlsrv_52_ts_vc6.dll`
and `extension = php_pdo_sqlsrv_52_ts_vc6.dll` But nothing works I get always the same error from the connection:

```
Fatal error: Undefined class constant 'SQLSRV_ATTR_DIRECT_QUERY' in
```

Any idea what's wrong?

Thanks.

Oskar

Comment: SQLSRV doesn't support your OS. see http://www.php.net/manual/en/sqlsrv.requirements.php

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the PDO driver installed - https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098

Comment: Thank you! I'm actually trying to use PHP 7.4, which ended in me needing to download two drivers: The [PHP for SQL server driver version 5.8](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/release-notes-php-sql-driver?view=sql-server-ver16#previous-releases) (NOT the latest version. The latest version doesn't support PHP 7.4), and the [ODBC driver version 17.10.5](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/windows/release-notes-odbc-sql-server-windows?view=sql-server-ver16#previous-releases)

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error `Undefined class constant 'SQLSRV_ATTR_DIRECT_QUERY'` while trying to install `PHP 7.4` on an IIS machine, and I ended up needing to download two drivers:

The [PHP for SQL server driver version 5.8](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/release-notes-php-sql-driver?view=sql-server-ver16#previous-releases) (NOT the latest version. The latest version doesn't support PHP 7.4).

and the [ODBC driver version 17.10.5](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/windows/release-notes-odbc-sql-server-windows?view=sql-server-ver16#previous-releases) (Again, **not** the latest version, which as of this moment is 18.3.2)

As well as verify that you're using PHP NTS(`Non Thread Safe`). (We got stuck for a while, because our PHP drivers wouldn't load correctly, because we weren't using PHP NTS.)